# Which Darshana ShAstras were available during the Krita and TretA yugas?

Tags: yuga, shad-darshana

We know that in Hinduism we have the six philosophies (Darshana) collectively known as the Shadadarshana.

They are- SAmkhya, PAtanjala, NyAya, Vaisheshika, PurvamimAmsA and Uttara MimAmsA (also known as VedAnta).

My questions:

1) Out of these six Darshanas which ones were available in [Krita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satya_Yuga) and [TretA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treta_Yuga) yugas ( when the people were more strong both physically and intellectually as well as more righteous)?

2) Also, if more than one were available, do we also know which one among them was the more (or the most) "popular" (one)?