# Which is the oldest school of thought in Hinduism?

Tags: history, schools

There are 6 schools of thought in Hinduism(astika). So which is the oldest of all the schools?

Comment: Samkhya is the oldest

Comment: @Rickross okk, but how old

Comment: I don't know how old but I know that it's the oldest among the 6 that exist

Comment: There is no start-date for any school of thought. Because these are not inventions, but discoveries. None of the darshana-sthapaks (school 'establishers') are darshana-kartas (school 'founders') - none of them claim that they've come up with it originally AFAIK.

Comment: @mar some must have found it. Like gravity, it was discovered by Sir Isaac Newton **[1642-1727]**. So when did a Sage found Samkhya

Comment: BTW I have asked a somewhat related Q earlier: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/which-darshana-shastras-were-available-during-the-krita-and-treta-yugas @DarkKnight

Comment: @Rickross thanks for it. Anyway no one answered it

Comment: Yes so far no one is able to answer it @DarkKnight